# Cos(x/5)=(-1/3)? How many solutions for x in interval [-2π, 2π]?

Tags: trigonometry

I know that the all real solution is x=9.55316618 ± 10πn, 4.37254676 ± 10πn'.

I know how to get x=9.55316618 ± 10πn, but the second part, 4.37254676 ± 10πn I don't know how to get. Can anyone show me the steps to get 4.37254676 ± 10πn, and how many solutions x as in the in the interval  [-2π, 2π]?

Comment: Wolfram alpha is showing that 4.37... is not a solution.

Comment: There are no solutions to $\cos\frac{x}{5}=-\frac{1}{3}$ for $x\in[-2\pi,2\pi]$.